# Show/hide div based on select option not working

Tags: javascript, html

ey, I have 1 option in my selector list, and I want the div to not display with that one is selected. And when another is selected its back.

HTML:

```js
function weg() {
  var x = document.getElementById("wegwezen");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
}   else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="cars" class="" style="border:0px;border-bottom:1px solid #b70000;margin-left: 128px;width:200px;" id="state" onchange="myfun()">
 <option value="behandeling" onclick="weg();" selected>Soort behandeling</option>
 <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
 <option value="saab">Saab</option>
 <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
 <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<div id="wegwezen"><p><b>Behandeling:</b>   <span id="pr"></span>  €00,00</p></div>
```

So when "Soort behandeling" is selected the div needs to hide. But it just hides and then only comes back when I select that one again. Does someone know what causes this?

Comment: Where is the `myfun()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `this` into your function call to `weg()`. Then remove the `onclick` on your first `option` as this is not needed.

In your `weg` function accept the `this` argument (here I called it `elem`) and use that to get the value of the selected item using `elem.value`. Based on the value, you can then choose whether show or hide the element using the element's `.style` property.

Lastly, as the 1st option is selected as default, you need to hide the div initially. You can do this by adding the `style="display: none;"` to your div.

See working example below:

```js
function weg(elem) {
  var x = document.getElementById("wegwezen");
  if(elem.value !== "behandeling") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="cars" class="" style="border:0px;border-bottom:1px solid #b70000;margin-left: 128px;width:200px;" id="state" onchange="weg(this)">
  <option value="behandeling" selected>Soort behandeling</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<div id="wegwezen" style="display: none;">
  <p><b>Behandeling:</b> <span id="pr"></span> €00,00</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I think your logic is contrary of what OP needs, you are showing the div when `value=behandeling` is selected, he wants to hide.

Comment: @CalvinNunes ah, sorry. I miss interpreted the question. I've fixed my answer now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

**Use this one. I hope this will works for you.**

```js
function weg(elem) {
  var x = document.getElementById("wegwezen");

if(elem.value == "behandeling"){
x.style.display = "none";
}

else{

  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
}   
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="cars" class="" style="border:0px;border-bottom:1px solid #b70000;margin-left: 128px;width:200px;" id="state" onchange="weg(this)">
 <option value="behandeling" selected>Soort behandeling</option>
 <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
 <option value="saab">Saab</option>
 <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
 <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<div id="wegwezen" style="display:none;"><p><b>Behandeling:</b>   <span id="pr"></span>  €00,00</p></div>
```